# Multicore simulation of a single FMU

Tags: python, parallel-processing, openmodelica, fmi, pyfmi

Is it possible to take a single FMU and simulate it via model exchange in python on multiple in parallel to speed up a simulation?

The models are created with OpenModelica, imported via PyFMI and solved with scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.

Comment: For an example realizing this with fmpy see https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/master/fmpy/examples/parameter_variation.py (this example is for a CS FMU but can be adapted to ME)